# AdMob AdView overlaping Listview in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to show an AdView in my Android app. 
I have a RelativeLayout like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaFicheros"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sinFicheros"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/SinFicheros" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I add the AdView programmatically (I need to) and set the layout like this:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ID_EDITOR);

ListView listaFicheros = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaFicheros);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, listaFicheros.getId());
adView.setLayoutParams(adLayoutParams);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams listaLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
listaLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, adView.getId());
listaFicheros.setLayoutParams(listaLayoutParams);

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
```

The Adview is showing properly at the bottom of the screen but my problem is the AdView is overlaping the last item of the ListView and i can't see it.

Anyone can help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the layout params for listaFicheros to MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT (ie take over the whole of the parent's view, and you have told the AdView to align it's bottom with the bottom of listaFicheros. This is why you have an overlap.

There are several ways to resolve this. Suggest you change AdView to be ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM. **Strongly** suggest you construct the AdView in xml as it will help you think about your layout more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Finally moved to LinearLayout and everything was OK. Even so, I can not add AdView to xml since is a library project and I want to make 2 versions of app (one of them without ads) so I add the AdView only in the free version :)

Comment: You could still add the AdView via XML and then hide it in your version without ads.

Comment: Sure, but the app code gets more clear adding it dinamically (I'm checking the version of the app that way), or that's what I thought ;). Anyway, thanks for the help.